# Multiplication of tensors in a python list with a constant variable in tensorflow

Tags: matrix, tensorflow, product

I have a 1D python list called `x`, of shape `(1000)` which contains tensor elements of shape `(3, 600)`. I also have a tensorflow variable `w` of shape `(600, 1)` which I would like to multiply to each tensor element of `x`. The result of each operation would be a tensor of shape `(3, 1)`.

Is there any way to efficiently apply `w` to each element of `x`? The logic using a python loop would be:

```
for i in range(1000):
    x[i] = tf.matmul(x[i], w)
```

I already tried the following:

```
w = [w] * 1000
result = tf.mul(x, w)
```

But I got the following error:

```
ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 3 and 600 for 'Mul' (op: 'Mul') with input shapes: [1000,3,600], [1000,600,1]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into using tf.map_fn which maps a function along the first axis of a tensor.  In you case you have x is a tensor of shape (1000, 3, 600).  It does not matter that the first dim is a list.  It will just act as a tensor.

`tf.map_fn(lambda x_: tf.matmul(x_, W), x)`

You could also use the tf.batch_matmul operation as follows.

`tf.batch_matmul(x, [w] * 1000)`

However I would use tf.tile instead of [w] * 1000

Comment: Thanks, both worked! `tf.batch_matmul` seemed to be faster however.

Comment: Yeah.  For some reason though I don't think it broadcasts.  Kind of annoying that you have to tile the first dim.